# Boiling vegetables for an hour and retention of their nutrients

Tags: nutrition, micronutrients, vegetable

I boil broccoli, eggplants, courgette/zucchini and okra for an hour on high heat before eating them, because I prefer them totally soft so that I don't have to chew them (for personal reasons, irrelevant here). But does it kill the ingredients in them? If yes, then which ingredients?

If necessary, I should pont out that I don't like to fry them, as I don't want to add any extra oil, and also it won't give me the mashed, soft texture I'm looking for.

If I don't drain the water used for boiling, then am I still getting all the nutrients from these vegetables? Here by nutrients, I meant all the vitamins and the minerals (e.g. calcium, iron etc.).

Comment: I would ask if you consume the water, but even if you do I would expect that most vitamins have been destroyed by such prolonged cooking.

Comment: Welcome! That's broad. Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we *require* prior research info of you when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you are ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. Most important: what are 'nutrients' and effect of heat?

Answer (score 1):

Minerals are not destroyed by cooking, but a large amount of some minerals, especially potassium, can leak into the boiling water. This can be prevented by *steaming* - cooking *above* instead *in* the boiling water.

More than 50% of some vitamins can be destroyed by cooking; the percent increases with cooking time.

Source: [Nutritional Effects of Food Processing (NutritionData)](https://nutritiondata.self.com/topics/processing)